# Hard drives stopped showing up on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro from early 2011 (OS X El Captain v10.11.2) that recently just stopped connecting to any external hard drives. Everything worked fine before, and suddenly all external HDs stopped appearing in the Finder, Disk Utility and the command line (by running `diskutil list`)...

Two things I noticed:

- The HDs are powered up and I can hear they are spinning.
- The HDs work perfectly on any other machines.

I would really appreciate if some of you could give me a hand with this, it doesn't make any sense to me...! Anything similar someone has experienced? Anything I should try to check?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: 
Problem is now solved.

And in order to learn something, does anyone see any logical explanation to this? Why would HDs just stop appearing, and appear again after a reboot?

Comment: Tried a different cable, different port; tested the current port works for any other device; Rebooted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rebooting solved the problem, thank you Tetsujin

(Answering to mark the question as solved)